# Disable the navigation arrow in caldroid

Tags: android

I want to disable the navigation arrow in cal droid or else i want to reduce the size of navigation arrow in caldroid. Anyone give solution for this problem. If i give the
`dialogCaldroidFragment.setShowNavigationArrows(false);`
means the navigation arrow does not hide.

Comment: I have strucked in last two days

Answer (score 0):

This is work for me

```
    @Override
public void onCaldroidViewCreated() {
    if (caldroidFragment.getLeftArrowButton() != null) {
    caldroidFragment.setShowNavigationArrows(false);
    }
}
```